# Excel 2010: How do I change the look of the dialog box(s)/Pop-up windows?

Tags: playonlinux, appearance, microsoft-office

I installed **MS Office 2010** on Ubuntu 12.04.2, and everything looks normal and functions as it would on a normal Windows machine.

**EXCEPT**: When I click save, or save as, the dialog box looks like its from Windows 98 or something. It shows up as the OLD gray, square, boxy type; rather than the faded/tinted blue, rounded corners, eye candy we've come to expect from Microsoft.

How do I change this? Is there a setting I can change *within* Excel or Word? I know you can change the appearance of ALL your programs in Windows this way using the start menu (usually the only reason being to increase performance), but I'm using Ubuntu and do not have the "Start Menu" privilege.

It's just strange that the Word and Excel programs open and look perfect, but the "Save"/"Save As" dialog boxes look like they're from Windows 98...

Actually, now that I think about it, they look like Ubuntu dialog boxes...

So how do I change this WITHIN the programs Word and Excel? (I'm assuming the answer, whatever it is, applies to PPT, Outlook, and OneNote as well)

Here is a screen shot of what I'm looking at:
[image]

Here is another screen shot from when I click on the 'Page Layout' tab, then click the bottom right hand arrow under 'Page Setup':
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you are looking for, but I that's how Wine works, and you can't change it from the applications. These dialogs are WinAPI calls, which are run by Wine, using the Windows theme of Wine.

I hope someone proves me wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One thing I tried was going to "configure wine" from the Dash, and under the applications tab "Windows version" was set to Windows XP, so I changed it to Windows Vista, but that didn't work...     So, still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try under "Configure Wine", the "Desktop Integration" option, which has the option to install "Themes" as well as spaces for fonts, sizes, etc. (See screenshot)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRFl2.png)